# Rails match user_id column in table A to user_id column in table B then use table B data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an articles table in my Rails project for making news articles. In that table I have a user_id column which populates the column with the current_user id. I then have a Drivers table which has the same name field user_id.

What I want to do is create a variable called @author and then use the data in the Drivers table (like name, profile pic etc)

*The error i'm getting now is "undefined method `profile_pic' for #Article::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fac792a7678"*

My article model is this:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :drivers
  #has_many :comments
end
```

My drivers model is:

```
class Driver < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
end
```

and finally in my articles_controller i've tried to match both fields:

```
def show
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   @driver = Article.where(user_id: Driver.pluck(:user_id))
end
```

Any direction is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you have a many to many relationship between articles and drivers, you should use a `has_many :through` association. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

If an article can have many drivers, which one do you want to use to get the name/profile pic/etc? the first one?

You can do something like `@driver = @article.drivers.first` if you want to get the first driver from the current article.

Comment: Thanks. That was a mistake. Each article should only have one driver.

Comment: then your article should `belong to` a driver (with a driver_id column), and then you do `@driver = @article.driver` to get that article's driver